# Laravel Validator Facade - Validate size based on another field value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

I have a form where the user must define the number of items to save and when you submit the form and parse it to JSON it looks like this:

```
{
 "numItems": 3,
 "items": [
     "1" : {"A": "Foo", "B:"bar"},
     "2" : {"A": "Foo", "B:"bar"},
     "3" : {"A": "Foo", "B:"bar"},
 ],
}
```

And I want to validate that the number of items inside `items` matches with the value of `numItems`.

I've tried with:

```
$aValidations = [
    "numItems" => "required|int|max:10",
    "items" => "required|array|size:numItems",
]
```

But even if the number of item matches the `numItems` value I get this:

```
{
    "message": "The given data was invalid.",
    "errors": {
        "items": ["The items must contain numItems items."]
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why can't you just pull the count in PHP? If you're going to go this far to validate the list of n elements really is n, then you might as well just get it yourself.

Comment: You are using the `size` rule incorrectly. 

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-size. Instead of `size:numItems`, use `size: 3` for your example.

Comment: I think that it would be better to be able to do the validation in both ways, and the docs isn't clear enough. It would be better to say that `value` must be an integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to write a custom validator (you can put this in your AppServiceProvider@boot method). Something like (not tested/pseudocode):

```
Validator::extend('coolValidatorName', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
        $data = $validator->getData();
        return $data[$parameters[0]] == count($value)
    });
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#custom-validation-rules

Comment: I think that creating my own validator would be a better and reusable approach to the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

The [size rule](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Validation/Concerns/ValidatesAttributes.php#L1282) accepts a numeric value which it then compares against the size of the input[1], it does not accept a field reference.

If you would like to compare against the value taken from another field you will need to pass in that field value yourself, e.g:

```
$aValidations = [
    "numItems" => "required|int|max:10",
    "items" => "required|array|size:" . $data->get('numItems'),
]
```

note: assumption has been made that you have decoded your json and then created a collection.

e.g:

```
$json = '{"numItems":4,"items":[{"a":"foo","b":"bar"},{"a":"foo","b":"bar"},{"a":"foo","b":"bar"}]}';

$data = collect((array) json_decode($json));

$aValidations = [
    "numItems" => "required|int|max:10",
    "items" => "required|array|size:" . $data->get('numItems'),
];
```

[1] For a string it compares the number of characters, for an integer it compares the values as is, for an array it compares the count of top level elements and for a file it compares the file size.

Comment: This can be a way, but it would get the value before making sure that is valid.

Comment: The rules run in order, meaning that if `numItems` does not pass validation then the validation will fail regardless. That said, if it's important each of your rules is correct at all times then you could do something like `min($data->get('numItems', 10))` which will guarantee your `size` rule is never greater than your maximum allowed amount.